Why do I have two different Source Control tabs with different functions in VS Code?
Not sure when this happened but my VS Code app (version 1.93.0) has two different sidebar tabs named "Source Control", but they do different things. One is for actual source control, the other contains the file explorer, search bar, and outline. What exactly is going on here?



I figured it out, you can drag the options from a tab into another tab to combine them. The heading "Source control" is just based on what the options within the tab are
